# Configuring servlet for using spring

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, servlets

How to configure my web application in Eclipse (based on Servlets and deployed to Tomcat) to use Spring framework. I need only IoC container (Beans only and ApplicationContext), not Spring MVC. How to configure web.xml for this?

Regards

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way is to put this in your `web.xml`:

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    </listener-class>
</listener>
```

and have `applicationContext.xml` in `WEB-INF`, or have its location configured this way (in `web.xml` again)

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        classpath:applicationContext.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>
```

Comment: @skaffman - yes, thanks. I'm always configuring it to be on classpath so I forgot the default :)